# External Display No Longer Has Full Capabilities when Changing Cable

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on Asus A455L. I have a BenQ T52WA monitor connected via VGA cable. Earlier, Ubuntu detects it just fine. When I open Display settings it says it's a BenQ 15", and it has many resolution options including 1280x720 which is its native.

However, the signal cable was deteriorating and the display flickers every time I touch it. So I bought a new one. Now the display is just detected as "Unknown display" and has only 4:3 resolution options.

Can I maybe install a driver to restore the resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a hardware issue rather than a driver issue. Try using your old cable and see if it still works. If it does, your new cable is problematic. If not, there might be a driver issue.

Comment: With my old cable the monitor is identified well. I wonder if VGA cables transmit device's resolution info.

Comment: There's something called a [Display Data Channel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel?wprov=sfla1) that allows the output device to detect resolution, refresh rate and other parameters. One of the DDC pins could be broken in your new cable.

Comment: I resorted to using my old cable, I just swapped the ends so the one with loose connector wouldn't be disturbed too often. The distortion with the new cable strains my eyes and it throws off my mouse movements.

Comment: There are cables out there  that don't have a cable on every pin. Typically  they are thinner and cheaper. They are from the era when monitors were unintelligent. Find yourself a multimeter and the VGA pin layout and do some measuring on both cables.